# Do Google Chrome desktop applications need to have an appearance?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, message-passing

Is it possible to create a Google Chrome desktop application that runs only as a process in the background which the user cannot directly interact with?

My idea is to create a Chrome browser extension that the user interacts with and that will, via message passing, send data to a Chrome desktop app to operate on before sending it back to the browser extension. I want the operations of the desktop app to be completely invisible to the user.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply ignore the onLaunched event, or create a hidden window:

```
chrome.app.window.create("main.html", { hidden: true })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can hide the window on app start with chrome.app.window.current().hide()